# Why does this piece of python code return true?

Tags: python

```
rec = {"Name" : "Python", "Age":"20", "Addr" : "NJ", "Country" : "USA"}
id1 = id(rec)
del rec
print(id(id1))
rec = {"Name" : "Python", "Age":"20", "Addr" : "NJ", "Country" : "USA"}
id2 = id(rec)
print(id(id2))
print(id1 == id2)
```

This returns true. But the printed values are not same. What is the reason for this?

Values printed:

```
140647920868368
140647920868336
True
```

[image: Printed values of this code]

Comment: because `print(id(id2))` prints the *id of `id2`*

Comment: You print the id *of an id*. There is no reason for the id of two separate but equal numbers to be equal. Did you intend to `print(id1)` perhaps?

Comment: When I run your code, I get `True`, using CPython (from command line) but `False` if I use Colab. Of course `print(id1)` and `print(id2)` (without the outer call to `id`) print the same in CPython, but not in Colab. I can only guess this is related to how the interpreter assigns memory space. Also, if in CPython after getting `True` with your code I do `print(id1 is id2)`, the result is `False`, consisntent with the fact that `id1` and `id2` are stored in different places (and thus have different ids of their own).

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing `id1` and `id2`, you're printing the `id` of `id1` and `id2`. In other words, so you're not printing what you're comparing.

`id`s may get reused over the runtime of a program, anyway, and there's usually little reason to look at an object's `id` anyway.